# Rails saving two different model instances as a singular transaction

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing a service object for a sign up form that records data for a User and a Company model (FYI, I flat out refuse to use nested_attributes).

A User cannot exist without the presence of a Company (belongs_to).

**IF** the company succeeds and the user does not succeed in saving, how do I roll back the creation of the company?

I have tests copied below to demonstrate the point..

```
  context 'when both are valid?' do
    subject { -> { sign_up_object.save } }
    it { should change(Company, :count).by(1) }
    it { should change(sign_up_object, :company).to be_a Company }
    it { should change(User, :count).by(1) }
    it { should change(sign_up_object, :user).to be_a User }
  end
  context 'when COMPANY is invalid' do
    subject { -> { sign_up_object.save } }
    before { allow_any_instance_of(Company).to receive(:save!).and_return false }
    it { should change(User, :count).by(0) }
    it { should change(Company, :count).by(0) }
  end
  context 'when USER is invalid' do
    before { allow_any_instance_of(User).to receive(:save!).and_return false }
    subject { -> { sign_up_object.save } }
    it { should change(User, :count).by(0) }
    it { should change(Company, :count).by(0) }  ->>>> this one fails!!!
  end
```

The code I have at the moment looks something like this

```
class SignUp

  ......

  def save_resources
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      save_company
      save_user
    end
  end

  def save_company
    company = new_company
    self.company = company if company.save!
  end

  def save_user
    user = new_user
    self.user = user if user.save!
  end
end
```

I'm sure the `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` block isn't actually doing anything, as my tests show the user spec as the only one as failing, as a company count is going up by 1.

Comment: You need to use the bang method variation to raise an error i.e `user.save!` and `company.save!`

Comment: I have Ill update sorry

Comment: @j-dexx even with the bang the same test still fails. a company is still created while the user throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could manually rollback the transaction when user is not created:

Taking up your example:

```
class SignUp

  ......

  def save_resources
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      save_company
      save_user
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback if self.user.nil?
    end
  end

  def save_company
    company = new_company
    self.company = company if company.save!
  end

  def save_user
   user = new_user
   self.user = user if user.save!
 end
end
```

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: See my edited answer and let me know if it works for you or you need more explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can just destroy company if user.save is unsuccsessful

```
def save_resources    
  company = save_company
  user = save_user
  company.destroy if user.nil?
end
```

Comment: this seems, for want of a better word, a bit crappy. Wouldn't you agree? Surely there is a more elegant way to make the whole event atomic.

Comment: @rico_mac No way. You're trying to change the whole architecture for the edge case. While `if` covers that 0.1% probability.